# In what order should hard mode bosses be fought?

Tags: terraria

Now that I'm in hard mode, I'm wondering which boss to try and tackle first. In pre-hard mode, I fought the bosses in this order:

1. Eye of Cthulhu
2. Eater of Worlds / Brain of Cthulhu
3. Skeletron
4. Wall of Flesh

I have a full set of [Palladium armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Palladium_armor), and a [Night's Edge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Night%27s_Edge) as my primary weapon. However, I was recently destroyed by [The Twins](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Twins) after they spawned randomly (a simultaneous Blood Moon event didn't help).

Is there a boss I should be focusing my efforts on first? Are the strategies for fighting bosses much different than in pre-hard mode?

Comment: Well with 3 of the Hardmode bosses just being stronger prehardmode bosses, those fights are basically the same.

Comment: There is one other pre-hardmode boss you missed, go look around in the jungle, and look for beehives who need a smashing.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but your question is answered in [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/271124/145980).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no standard order to kill bosses.
It depends on your armor, weaponry and (by my own experience) [Mythril Armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mythril_armor) is needed for any of them.
It's probably the best to do it like this:

- [The Destroyer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Destroyer)
- [The Twins](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Twins)
- [Skeleton Prime](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Skeletron_Prime)

It's recommended to have a good piercing weapon for Destroyer.
[The Destroyer strategies page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:The_Destroyer_strategies) would help you.
After killing The Destroyer, you can kill The Twins very easily by using the [The Megashark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Megashark).
But Skeleton Prime is different from others. [Hallowed armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_armor) is recommended to defeat it.

Comment: What is really needed for the twins is the ability to move at a good clip as they will have NO problem keeping up with you. People often tackle them last simply because of that. Get some good motion and a gun with crystal bullets and they are farmable.

Comment: This answer lacks the following hard bosses: plantera, golem, mourning wood and pumpking, but is otherwise good.

Comment: I personally think that Turtle Armour would work better than just Hallowed, and, what about the Terra Blade and the other special weapons?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say:
(Even though I haven't fought them this order)

- The Destroyer
- The Twins
- Skeletron Prime

Now, if you want to fight the rest, you have to do:

- Plantera
- Golem

It's the only way the Plantera-Golem thing works!  Also, I'd recommend:

- The Destroyer: Better than Molten Armor & Night's Edge
- The Twins: Better than the armor for The Destroyer and Megashark
- Skeletron Prime, Plantera, and Golem: Better, again, and the Megashark (again).

Answer (score 3):

**Destroyer**

- At least molten armor

**The twins**

- Megashark
- mytill armor

**Skeleton prime**

- Excalibur or terra blade
- hallowed armor

Order

- Destroyer
- The twins
- Skeletron prime

**Plantera**

- Hallowed armor
- True Excalibur or True night edge

**Golem**

- adamantite armor
- bulb gun
- nights edge

**Ocram (console only)**

- hallowed armor Megashark

**Order**

- Ocram
- Plantera
- Golem

**Hardmode Event bosses**

- Ice queen
- Pumpking
- Everscream
- Morning wood
- Santa NK1

**Pumpkin moon**

- Morning wood
- Pumpking

**Frost moon**

- Santa NK1
- Everscream
- Ice queen.

**Defeat**

- To defeat all of them hallowed armor rainbow rod star cannon terra blade
  That's all

Comment: i see no change and trying to read it it seems to read like a list, maybe using bulleted lists (8th button across) might help if you answer is meant to be a list

Comment: i have tried to fix it so please review it, i normally avoid doing formatting for users cause i have no idea what their intention was

Comment: all answer formatting can be done just by typing, for example, a bulleted list is a new line with a space, a - and another space before the text, bolding is done by adding 2 * on either side of the text

Comment: + you messed it up frost moon is with punking

Comment: as i said, i have tried to do the formatting but it's hardly perfect and your the best person to do formatting, making lists is as easy as copying what's already there and altering it which can be done with an ipad (as with any formatting on SE Posts if your using the stranded ipad onscreen keyboard)

Comment: Please refrain from extensive comments.

Comment: Do not edit okay please it's perfect

Comment: Please like this ⬆ do that

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are good at.
I usually fight the twins first because you can buy leaf wings from the witch doctor 
and you can get the clockwork assault rifle from the WoF. dodging while shooting takes practice but can kill the twins without too much trouble.
The skeletron prime is probably the easiest hardmode boss to beat with almost any good ranged weapon as long as you have lighting boots.
the destroyer contrary to what others say is probably the hardest boss to beat in early hardmode I would recommend a good piercing weapon or flamethrower.

so in short there are some combinations:
1. twins with CaR or uzi
2. the destroyer with Magical harp
3. skeletron prime with megashark

alternately, 
1. skeletron prime with CaR or uzi
2. the destroyer with flamethrower 
3. the twins with megashark

1. the destroyer with adamantium repeater or golden shower or dao of pow or glaive/ phasesaber with pain.
2. the twins or skeletron prime with megashark.
   You can beat duke fishron before fighting the moon events.
   you definetly want to beat plantera and get turtle or shroomite or spectre armor before fighting the pumpkin moon then frost moon. you have to beat plantera to get the pumpkin moon medallion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing The Destroyer, because he's just like a big (I mean huge) Eater of Worlds. Then go onto The Twins first, because they are just like the Eye of Cthulhu.

Then you should go onto Skeletron Prime.
He is the bigger Skeletron.
I would recommend you have the legendary frostbrand to kill Skeletron Prime. But mainly just wings and mega shark with crystal and cursed bullets

Answer (score 0):

I would do the destroyer skeletron  prime the the twins with andamantite/titanium armor. If you beat the destroyer first  you can make a mega shark and don't listen yak anyone one else make a mega shark first!!! In order to beat the destroyer I would recommend full mythril/orchilume and use golden shower with the mana flower

Answer (score 0):

Kill the twins first because he drops souls of sight for magical harp the kill the destroyer with it because it pierces. Then craft the mega shark which you can use to kill sketron prime!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Demon Sickle, Terra blade, and megashark and/or Uzi for the first three battles. They are not required but can prove useful.

I would say that you should do the destroyer but do it close to your house because if you die it will follow and you can do constant damage. Then do the twins, once again close to your house because you need constant damage. After that do skeleton prime but this boss is challenging so I recommend doing some research. Use potions if you just have hallowed armor because that is not good enough to beat him easily. After that you could do ocram if your on console or Plantera. Plantera basically is a stopping point because you can do very little unless you beat Plantera. Get turtle armor or whatever equal armor corresponds to you class for this fight because you can't beat it with hallowed armor unless your a pro. Fight golem next but be careful of his laser beam attacks that shoot you through blocks. Then I think you should prepare much more and get good armor for the pumpkin moon and after you survive all waves prepare more if you can and fight the frost legion. No more bosses to fight anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Fight the destroyer first because with a cutlass (a rare drop from pirates) because it's really fast and mine does more damage then the legendary Excalibur. Then the twins because with the mega shark and a reaper scythe you will die a few times but the scythe is really useful because it flings a magic scythe and it doesn't consume mana so you can just spam it and kill them in one night.then skeletron prime withe the mega shark hallowed armor and the scythe but aim for its head and dodge him as much as you can other wise you will die and he will de spawn and you will have to make another mechanical skull to try again. Then to plantera a few times to get some temple keys to make biome keys to get awesome weapons to fight the golem to get a heat ray to fight ocram because it has killed the destroyer in about 3 seconds so you could kill ocram within a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

1.Destroyer - I killed him with mythril armor and nights edge / dark lance

2.The Twins - I killed him with full adamantite fighting set / can replace repeater with sharanga / spectre boots with angel or demon wings

3.Skeletron Prime - I killed him with titan or dragon armor / vulcan repeater or megashark / spectre boots with angel or demon wings

I played the android version so dont blame me if you cant get some of these

Answer (score -1):

Duke fishron is so easy fight him a lot (fish in ocean with truffle worm) then you have good loot then do twins then destroyer then skeletron prime then plantera then golem.

Comment: Why this order?  What does this order go for the player?

Answer (score -2):

kill the destroyer since he drop souls of might than you can easily craft a maga shark which will help you with the twins and then deal with skeloron prime

Answer (score -2):

Kill the Destroyer with at least Mythril Armor, and an Adamantite Repeater (Jesters Arrows or Unholy). Then, kill the Twins with Adamantite Armor and the Megashark, then kill Skeletron Prime with Adamantite Armor and Megashark or Hallowed Repeater.

Next is Plantera. You need Hallowed or Frost Armor to defeat it. Then, the Golem is next. For the Golem, you need Chlorophyte Armor to defeat him. Lastly, Duke Fishron requires top tier armor (Shroomite, Beetle, or Spectre).

Answer (score -2):

beat The Twins first with Adamantite armor (melee set), about 3 Greater healing potions, and an adamantite repeater.  Kill the destroyer with Hallowed armor, plus a hallowed repeater. Then, skeletron prime with a hallowed armor, plus three light discs.
Have full hallowed armor (melee), a dao of pow, and a megashark. Fight the golem and use the flower pow and the inferno fork. Kill ocram, then. Use inferno fork until 1/2 health while being grappled to a heart statue. Get off the heart statue when he gets to low health, because even when youre on a heart statue at his second form, he does a crapton of damage!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Then, finish him off with a venus magmum.

Comment: This reads more like a description of your own adventure rather than an answer to the question. If you feel that your answer adds to the existing answers, please reword it to focus on the question asked.